# How to set DisableSystemTextJsonSourceGenerator from build.props file?

Tags: c#, msbuild, system.text.json

I'm having the same issue reported here:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61602#issuecomment-971824612

basically: trying to use System.Text.Json 6 in a dotnetapp3.1 application (which cannot be upgraded at the moment). This causes that the source generators to break the build.

One workaround suggested was to pass `DisableSystemTextJsonSourceGenerator=true` to the `dotnet build` command.

I tried that in the command line as `-p:DisableSystemTextJsonSourceGenerator=true` but the build still fails.
It's also mentioned is possible to pass it throuh the directory.builds.props but I don't know how to do that.

How do you pass that parameter in that file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the property in question and the use-case, but syntax-wise, your `Directory.Build.props` should contain the following:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DisableSystemTextJsonSourceGenerator>true</DisableSystemTextJsonSourceGenerator>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Since it does not work as a CLI parameter, I would be surprised if the `Directory.Build.props` worked. They both do the same thing.